# генерация с острова с помощью diamond-square

Tags: java, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток.

Я пытаюсь использовать diamond-square для генерации ландшафта. Задача получить остров расположенной посреди океана. У меня же выходит несколько кусков суши между которыми расположены заливы. Я поступал следующим образом: в углах карты задавал минимальное значение, а в центре максимальное. Но остров я так и не получил. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью diamond-square получить остров окруженный океаном?

Comment: а что вы получили?

Comment: Несколько больших кусков суши разделенные проливами. При этом суша может касаться границы карты.